# Adding Clickable Results To Google Maps Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am trying to add custom results to autocomplete and am having some luck, but I cannot make the results clickable.  A left or right click does absolutely nothing.  Consider the following code:

```html
<input type="text" name="query" id="query">
<script>
    var input = (document.getElementById('query'));
    var options = [];

    city = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(city, 'place_changed', function () {

        place = city.getPlace();


    });

    $("#query").on('input', function()
    {
        append_places($("#query").val());
    });

    var new_pac = false;
    function append_places(input)
    {
        if (!new_pac)
        {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                $(".pac-container").append('<div id="new-pac""></div>');
            }, 1);

            new_pac = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $('#new-pac').empty();
        }

        $("#new-pac").append('<div class="pac-item areasearch"><a href="http://www.wherever.com">Foo</a><span class="pac-icon pac-icon-areas"></span><a class="pac-item-query" href="http://www.wherever.com">test</a></div>');

    }

</script>
```

The new entry shows up, looks like a link, but doesn't react when clicked.  Any ideas on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Google Maps JS Demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) it seems that you are lacking a method to define the preferred viewport on the map to view the place. You need to add code where it will do something wether or not it was able to retrieve a place.

```
// If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
if (place.geometry.viewport) {
map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
}
```

Here's [another example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) for reference.